# Error when trying material-ui SelectField component

Tags: material-design, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying out material-ui right now. I am new to react.js and material-ui and somehow manage to go through some stuff, but cannot use the SelectField. Whenever I use the SelectField component, I get a

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefinederror.

I have followed how it is written in:[material-ui.com](http://material-ui.com/#/components/text-fields)

This is my `selectField.jsx` file:

```
var React = require('react');
var mui = require('material-ui');
var SelectField = mui.SelectField;
var ThemeManager = new mui.Styles.ThemeManager();
var Colors = mui.Styles.Colors;
var StyleResizable = mui.Mixins.StyleResizable;

var menuItems = [
{ payload: '1', text: 'Never' },
{ payload: '2', text: 'Every Night' },
{ payload: '3', text: 'Weeknights' },
{ payload: '4', text: 'Weekends' },
{ payload: '5', text: 'Weekly' },
];

var Main = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    return { selectValue: undefined};
  },

  childContextTypes: {
    muiTheme: React.PropTypes.object
  },

  getChildContext: function() {
    return {
      muiTheme: ThemeManager.getCurrentTheme()
    };
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <SelectField
      value={this.state.selectValue}
      onChange={this._handleSelectValueChange}
      floatingLabelText="Select Field"
      menuItems={menuItems} />
    );
  },

  _handleSelectValueChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({
      selectValue: e.target.value
    });
  }
});

module.exports = Main;
```

Any ideas why it outputs an error? Other material-ui components works fine.

EDIT:

This is my parent component in `app.jsx` file:

```
(function () {
  var React = require('react');
  var injectTapEventPlugin = require('react-tap-event-plugin');
  var Main = require('./components/selectField.jsx'); 

  window.React = React;

  injectTapEventPlugin();

  React.render(<Main />, document.body);

})();
```

Comment: Can you show the parent component as well?

Comment: @tobiasandersen Yes, added the parent component.

Comment: That exact code is working for me. Make sure you don't have different versions of React in your bundle. And also, I'd suggest you name the module to something other than Main (preferably close to the file name).

Comment: @tobiasandersen Thank you it worked after I updated my React and Material-ui. I just got them last Friday but I guess they updated it after that... And thank you for your suggestion. I will reflect it in my codes.

Comment: May be just update the material-ui version. I don't see any method toUpperCase in SelectField.